# How to enable encryption for CVS?

Tags: cvs

I want to access CVS when I'm outside the workplace. Is there a way to encrypt the authentication and file transfers that CVS normally does?

Answer (score 1):

CVS is almost always used remotely over SSH, which encrypts everything. This is the default for modern installations of CVS. You can use SSH's authentication (which can be by RSA or DSA key) for CVS on any modern operating system.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways of doing this.

For regular access you could use SSL VPN (Secure Sockets Layer Virtual Private Network).

For secure file transfers you could use SFTP (Secured File Transfer Protocol).